# SceneKit: How to detect contact without collision iOS

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I'm making a Space Shooter game on Scene Kit and I want the asteroids to explode when the ship gets contact with them, I don't want them to collide, I just want to know when they contact each other.

The problem is that I don't know how to implement a collision detection when the ship intersects the asteroid. Like for example, I want Xcode to log "COLLIDED" when they actually get contact with each other.

I already added the `categoryBitMask` and the `collisionBitMask` for both objects. So, how could I achieve this? By the way, I'm doing everything on Swift.

Comment: Are you actually using SpriteKit (2D) or SceneKit (3D)? `SCNPhysicsBody` doesn't have a `contactTestBitMask`.

Comment: I'm using SceneKit, my bad, I wrongly changed `categoryBitMask` for `contactTestBitMask`, I'll change it right now.

Answer (score 2):

SceneKit doesn't offer an option for separating contact detection from collision resolution for dynamic bodies. (If one of your bodies is a kinematic body, it won't have collisions resolved against it, but it won't be movable through physics either.) [File a feature request](http://bugreport.apple.com)?

However, it sounds like your use case is compatible with collision resolution — because the asteroids are exploding, you don't need to care about the effects of the collision on an asteroid (just remove it from the scene and replace it with explosion VFX, smaller asteroids, space slug, whatever). If the ship is meant to survive the collision and you don't want it to be affected by the collision, just set the relative masses of the ship and asteroid so that the asteroid won't impart significant momentum.

---

To do things when a collision occurs, you need to set a [contact delegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNPhysicsWorld_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SCNPhysicsWorld/contactDelegate) on your [scene's physics world](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNScene_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SCNScene/physicsWorld). In whatever class is serving as your contact delegate, implement the [`didBeginContact`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNPhysicsContactDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/SCNPhysicsContactDelegate/physicsWorld:didBeginContact:) method to be notified when a collision occurs.

In that method, you'll need to look at the contact's `nodeA` and `nodeB` to find out what categories of bodies collided (and which is which). Once you know that, e.g., `nodeA` is a ship and `nodeB` is an asteroid (or vice versa), you can kill the asteroid, update your score, etc.

Comment: I understand that when the asteroid gets contact with the spaceship the asteroid will be replaced by a VFX or whatever, the thing here is that how do I make Xcode to tell me when the asteroid gets contact with the spaceship? I want to know when does it happen, not what to do when it does happen.

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work with a much simpler answer.

On the node you want things to fall through, set the physics mass to a very small number:

```
ship.physicsBody.mass = 0.00000000000001;
```

Comment: And what does this is supposed to do?

Answer (score -2):

At the end I figured out how to solve this.

First I added the `categoryBitMask` and the `collisionBitMask` for both objects, the spaceship and the asteroids.

```
ship.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 2
asteroid.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 4

ship.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 4
ball.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 2
```

Then I gave a `dynamicBody()` to both of them.

```
ship.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody.dynamicBody()
asteroid.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody.dynamicBody()
```

Then I added a `NSTimer` to help me with the contact detection to update each 0.1 seconds to see if there is a contact.

```
override func viewDidLoad()
  {
       NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: "checkContact", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
  }

func checkContact()
{
  if (self.scene.physicsWorld.contactTestBetweenBody(ship.physicsBody, andBody: asteroid.physicsBody, options: nil) != nil)
     {
       println("CONTACT!")
     }
}
```

I didn't needed to add the `SCNPhysicsContactDelegate` to my view, but is better to add it to be sure there are no syntax problems or warnings.

And that's it!

NOTE: It's important to add a `dynamicBody()` or `staticBody()` to our 3D objects, otherwise it won't have a contact. And it's important to add the `dynamicBody()` or `staticBody()` to our 3D objects BEFORE we add them as a child to our scene.

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Don't do this. You're re-doing work that SceneKit already does for you, costing performance. First, scheduling an `NSTimer` is overkill — SceneKit already calls your `renderer(_:updateAtTime:)` method every frame if you have one. Second, SceneKit already checks for collisions every frame, so you're making it repeat that check.

Comment: If you're setting `ship.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask` before assigning `ship.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody.dynamicBody()`, the former is doing nothing — `physicsBody` is nil until you set one, so assigning to one of its properties through optional chaining does nothing.

Comment: Then, where does SceneKit checks for collisions every frame?

Comment: And actually I don't want them to collide, I want them just to contact, I don't care if the asteroid traspases the ship, I just want the program to tell me when they had a contact.

Comment: You don't need to do anything to tell SceneKit to render each frame — it just renders at whatever the `preferredFramesPerSecond` rate of your `SCNView` is. Part of its rendering process for each frame is processing actions, animations, and physics, and part of the physics processing is checking for contacts between all physics bodies in the scene. See the [SCNSceneRendererDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNSceneRendererDelegate_Protocol/index.html) documentation for info on the render loop.

Comment: Contact detection comes before collision resolution, so if you set a contact delegate and implement `didBeginContact`, that'll get called before the ship and asteroid bounce off each other and you can add whatever game logic you want at that time.

Comment: Okay, but where does I'm supposed to write my `contactTestBetweenBody` to be able to check the collision?

Comment: You don't. You get notified of contacts in your contact delegate. You only need to manually check for contacts if you've manually moved bodies around and want to know about contacts *before* the next frame renders. Or if you have game logic that wants to know more than the contact delegate tells you, like using `allContactedBodies`.